# Puppeteer page.mouse.down() / up() not the same as clicking physical mouse?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

At the following site, after entering a search phrase such as "baby" (try it!), the Puppeteer call `page.mouse.down()` doesn't have the same effect as clicking and holding the physical mouse: https://www.dextools.io/app/bsc

After entering a search phrase, a fake dropdown select menu appears, which is really an `UL`, and I am trying to click the first search result. So I use code like this

```
await page.mouse.move(200, 350); // let's assume this is inside the element I want
await page.mouse.down();
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // wait 2 secs
await page.mouse.up();
```

The expected effect of this code is that, for the 2 seconds that Puppeteer is "holding" the mouse button down, the fake dropdown stays visible, and when Puppeteer "releases" the mouse button, the site redirects to the search result for the item selected.

This is exactly what happens when I use the *physical* mouse.

However, what happens with Puppeteer is, the dropdown just disappears, as if I had hit the `Escape` key, and the `page.mouse.up()` command later has no effect any more.

I am aware that PPT has some quirks in respect to mouse, keyboard, holding and releasing buttons and modifier keys, especially when doing all of the above at once. For example, Drag & Drop doesn't work as expected, but none of the workarounds proposed here work for me: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the issue with this test script. The link is clicked with following navigation:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://www.dextools.io/app/bsc', { timeout: 0 });

  const input = await page.waitForSelector('.input-container input');
  await input.type('baby');

  const link = await page.waitForSelector('.suggestions-container.is-visible a:not(.text-sponsor)');
  await link.click();
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Comment: You are right, WTF!?! Now I need to understand what it is about my code that failed... and you win the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two separate mouse-down and up operations, you could try this according to [puppeteer docs](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pageclickselector-options):

```js
// selector would uniquely identify the button on your page that you would like to click
selector = '#dropdown-btn'
await page.click(selector, {delay: 2000})
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggestion, but it doesn't make a difference. Note that it is not my end goal to hold the fake dropdown for any length of time. My goal is to perform the search. That the dropdown disappears on mouse down, instead of mouse up, is more a symptom than the root of the problem. It shows us that physical mouse clicks (mouse down + mouse up) are "routed differently" to their destination in Chrome's DOM, than "virtual clicks" (the DOM events mouse down and mouse up). Somehow this website managed to listen to the physical "route" and ignore the "event-driven" route.

Comment: Thanks for the deeper explanation of the problem. It is puzzling. I wonder if you could try determining exactly what DOM events take place in the puppeteer vs when using a physical mouse to see which (if any) are lost in the puppeteer instance. If it is consistently lost (possibly due to the absence of a physical mouse), maybe you could temporarily attempt to manually trigger them? This [gist](https://gist.github.com/gabrielbusarello/181bf0ff6424c410a7137371f8a04af3) appears to manually trigger some events. I hope you have some luck in this!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the element of the list that you wanna click, you should look for the first `<a>` tag inside this element and use the reference you make on this `<a>` to perform a click.

From puppeteer's documentation it's saying if there is a navigation you should use:

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions),
  page.click(selector, clickOptions),
]);
```

where selector will be a reference to the mentioned `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, that is of course the first thing I tried, though I did not mention that. Clicking directly on a selector is always the easiest and straightforward way, but sites that don't want to be botted can notice these simple ways. I went to the move-mouse-then-click method because it is stealthier and less detectable by sites that watch for bots. So in short, I tried those more naive approaches first and unfortunately they all failed, so that's where I am with my mouse positioning and clicking.

Comment: Hmm ok, and could you make sure when clicking you're inside the element ?

Comment: "sites that don't want to be botted can notice these simple ways" -- were you actually blocked doing this or are you prematurely optimizing? `page.click` is a macro for moving the mouse to the element, firing down/up events. It doesn't use the native browser `el.click()`. I'd just do this. If you get blocked, why not try slowMo first before trying some drag & drop technique that doesn't seem relevant to the page? It seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377), or at least tangentially relevant to accomplishing X, to dip into how Puppeteer events work in general.

Comment: [puppeteer github - mouse helper](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/test/assets/input/mouse-helper.js)
With this helper you can actually see where the cursor is in non headless, so you could see if puppeteer is clicking the element.

Comment: Thanks, all suggestions that make complete sense, but fail to address the problem. Any which way I try mouse.down() or page.click(), the element in question "disappears" (maybe set to invisible?), and I am not being redirected to the anchor href. However, with a physical mouse click, the element stays (does not hide), and on release, it executes the <a href>, i.e. redirects me. Trust me, I have checked the x, y coordinates and the physical mouse cursor position. It is not a question of optimizing too soon, it doesn't work the slo-mo way either. if it worked, I'd live with the slo-mo way but...